# Chtml link failing

Tags: yii

I try to link from the site controller to another controller action using the Chtml::link, but it keeps redirecting me to the site/login page.

This code I have in the login view rendered from the site controller looks something like this:

```
<?php $this->beginWidget('system.web.widgets.CClipWidget', array('id'=>'Aboutinfo')); 
.
.
<?php echo CHtml::link('Learn more here', array('site/page','view'=>'about')); ?>
.
.
echo CHtml::link('Link label', array('othercontroller/action'));?>
.
.
<?php $this->endWidget();?>
```

Thanks for any suggestions/corrections for what I might be doing wrong

Comment: what's doing the redirect? does that other controller have authentication required?

Comment: @ldg I'm not what's causing the redirect. I click the link label and instead of opening the page corresponding to the action in the other controller, it just opens a blank page with the url pointing to site/login. If I remove the othercontroller/action, it opens the default site/index as I'd expect.

Comment: do you have some default settings that are requiring authentication for this controller?

Comment: @KieranAndrews thanks. I modified the controller's access rules and it works now

Answer (score 2):

Check the accessRules function in the controller you are trying to link to.  You should see something like this:

```
public function accessRules()
    {
        return array(
            array('allow', 
                'actions'=>array('index'),
                'users'=>array('*'),
            ),
            array('allow', 
                'actions'=>array('browse', 'add'),
                'users'=>array('@'),
            ),
            array('deny',  // deny all users
                'users'=>array('*'),
            ),
        );
    }
```

The 'users'=>array('*') means allow any user to access the action.  The line 'users'=>array('@') means allow only logged in users to access the action (browse & add in the above case).

Make sure your rule settings are correct.  I suspect the actions you are linking to have accessRules setup that require users to be logged in to view the page.  If the controller detects that the user is not logged in, it will redirect user to the login page.